# Не работает пример из книги Дейтелов.

Tags: c, указатели

Есть базовый код в книге который осуществляет пример объявления и использования массива указателей на функцию. При компиляции в Windows7 64x в среде DevC++ пишет ошибка в "void (*f[3])(int)= (function1, function2, function3);"

> [Warning] left-hand operand of comma is a reference, not call, to function `function1' > [Warning] right-hand operand of comma is a reference, not call, to function`function2' 
> invalid initializer

Можете объяснить чего пример не работает?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function1(int);
void function2(int);
void function3(int);

main()
{
  void (*f[3])(int)= (function1, function2, function3);
  int choice;

  printf("Enter a number between 0 and 2, 3 to end: ");
  scanf("%d", &choice);

  while (choice >= 0 && choice < 3)
  {
    (*f[choice])(choice);
    printf("Enter a number between 0 and 2, 3 to end: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
  }

  printf("You entered 3 to end\n");

  system("PAUSE");
}

void function1(int a)
{
  printf("You entered %d so function1 was called\n\n", a);
}

void function2(int b)
{
  printf("You entered %d so function2 was called\n\n", b);
}

void function3(int c)
{
  printf("You entered %d so function3 was called\n\n", c);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не знаю, какая там у Вас версия компилятора, но у меня заработало, когда я переписал с фигурными скобками.

```
void (*f[3])(int)= {function1, function2, function3};
```

если так не захочет, тогда придется писать так

```
void (*f[3])(int);
f[0] = function1;
f[1] = function2;
f[2] = function3;
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понимаю, чтоможно так, но хотелось как в примере) значит дело в компиляторе, MinGw барахлит( Надо в Линуксе смотреть.

Comment: нужно смотреть, какой именно у Вас minGW. Я в линуксе компилил gcc 4.7 (который по факту - тот же, что и mingw).

Также неплохо посмотреть в самой книге, какой именно компилятор они рекомендуют.

Comment: @steelhouse, в книге наверняка опечатка. 

**Правильно с фигурными скобками**.

--

В круглых же скобках получается просто выражение, точнее последовательность операторов. Что-то вроде несколько необычного (но вполне понятного):

    int a, b, c = (a = 1, b = ++a, a + b);
    printf ("(2 + 2 = 4) a = %d  b = %d  c = %d\n", a, b, c);

В Вашем случае результатом выражения 

    (function1, function2, function3)

будет просто адрес `function3` (как последнего оператора в списке), что не годиться (по крайней мере с т.з. компилятора) для инициализации массива из 3-х адресов функций.